# Performance Issue after Truncate and Load of a table in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, truncate

One of our clients has migrated from old to new (Larger size/resources) servers.
A process (X) is taking 4Hours extra whenever we are doing a truncate and full load of a Specific Table. If we do not truncate-load this table X doesnt take long to run, In process X we are inserting, updating and reading data from this table into numerous temp tables and then using these temp tables further.

I would like to know:

- Best Practices whenever a truncate and full load is performed
- What steps can we take from our side on this specific table?
- Does the database migration to another server bring such issues?
- What debugging should I do, I am doing gather stats with cascade after the 
  full load on this table, then running the process X
- is it recommended to update any Oracle parameters on moving from oracle 12c from Oracle 11g or 10?

sorry for being very generic, the exact usage of the table in process X is complex and difficult to mention here.
Please advise.

Comment: Is process X being executed while doing truncate and full load or after? And is this larger size/resourced server also fully dedicated for this database?

Comment: Yes X is executed after the full load of the table is complete.
We have seen the CPU and memory report that looks fine. We have a fully dedicated database server

Comment: Also to mention, the runtime of X looks dependent on the number of records inserted by the full load, more number of records more is the runtime of process X

Comment: Do you gather table statistics once it is loaded ? This could be the cause of heavy full table scan instead of fast index access.

Comment: yes, I did gather stats on the table with the following options:

dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(ownname=>'owner',
  tabname          => 'table',
  estimate_percent => dbms_stats.auto_sample_size,
  method_opt       => 'for all columns size auto',
  cascade=>TRUE, 
  DEGREE=>7)

after doing gather stats i run the process X

Comment: Can you compare the number of indexes for both cases - for the slow truncated-loaded version and for the version with fast X.

Comment: Checked the Indexes defined in both cases, they are same.
Should I check, in some way, the health of indexes?

Comment: What database version is your client having and did the migration involve any database upgrade? Also, are you doing an index rebuild after your truncate and full load?